# torch.Tensor() with requires_grad parameter

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I can't use torch.Tensor() with requires_grad parameter (torch version : 0.4.1)

without requires_grad :

```
x = torch.Tensor([[.5, .3, 2.1]])
print(x)
> tensor([[0.5000, 0.3000, 2.1000]])
```

with requires_grad=True or requires_grad=False :

```
x = torch.Tensor([[.5, .3, 2.1]], requires_grad=False)
print(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/_P/dev/ai/pytorch/notes/tensor01.py", line 4, in <module>
    x = torch.Tensor([[.5, .3, 2.1]], requires_grad=False)
TypeError: new() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (list, requires_grad=bool), but expected one of:
 * (torch.device device)
 * (torch.Storage storage)
 * (Tensor other)
 * (tuple of ints size, torch.device device)
      didn't match because some of the keywords were incorrect: requires_grad
 * (object data, torch.device device)
      didn't match because some of the keywords were incorrect: requires_grad
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are creating the tensor `x` by using the `torch.Tensor` class constructor which doesn't take the `requires_grad` flag. Instead, you want to use `torch.tensor()` (lowercase 't') method

```
x = torch.tensor([[.5, .3, 2.1]], requires_grad=False)
```

Edit: adding a link to docs: [torch.Tensor](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html)

Comment: Wondering why there are `torch.tensor` and `torch.Tensor`.

Comment: @EduardoReis I agree, this is very confusing behavior.